# Change Siri Search Engine iOS 9

Tags: ios, ipad, search, siri

I'm using Siri on an iPad Pro and I've set the default search engine in Settings > Safari to Bing but when I search for something with Siri it defaults to Baidu. I know that the default search engine works for Safari because when I type in the search bar it searches with Bing.

Search results for this don't apply to iOS 9. The iPad is new and there are no extensions on any sort installed. No data has been transferred from a backup. The only third party apps installed so far are MS Word, PowerPoint, and Excel.

How can I make Siri search with Bing?

Answer (score -1):

Until today, there's no way to do this. Here's my findings:

Siri doesn't perform search directly on baidu.com, it uses Siri's hideout [guzzoni.apple.com] to relay the request over (properly configured) TLS.

Other than asking for Apple's mercy, I think it's more probable to trade Chinese iPhone with one from another country.

BTW, the packets themselves are pretty fun to look at.